# Can I use OAuth and Auth at the same time in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth, laravel-passport

I am doing a project in which I have implemented private chat in Laravel. But for the third party, we use OAuth but i have already used auth() in my project. Can I use both? OAuth is getting token, then communicate with Vue.js. So, I don't want to remove auth() functions in my project. Can you please guide me what to do?

Real time chat system in laravel project. I'm using separate Vue.js with Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use both `OAuth` and default Laravel `Auth` at the same time. In default, Laravel provides routes as `web.php` and `api.php`.

`web.php`: This route uses default Laravel `Auth` functionality

`api.php`: Routes defined here uses `OAuth` functionality

Make sure you use default driver as `web` in `config/auth.php`

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Comment: Please do upvote and check this answer if this helps you 

Comment: bro i have one more thing . that if i get login with login api then can i access login user by auth()->user->id ?

Comment: Yeah. While doing login with API, you will get yourself an Authorization Token. Make sure you pass every request with middleware to parse in order to maintain Authorization. Then only you can access authorized User i.e. `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: I've actually used `JWT`, which is based on `OAuth Framework`. Its quite simple. And if you're using Laravel `5.4 or above`, user `JWT` of version `1.0 or above`. Look at these docs for Laravel: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth